# Android Toolbar buttons shadow

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I added this translucent gradient background to a Toolbar so buttons are noticeable on any background, but I wonder how to make a shadow just under the button itself instead of what I did?

[image]

Thank You

**EDIT**

So I realized the easiest way to achieve that is by setting a Drawable Resources.

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_home);
```

and

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="parent_theme">
    <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@drawable/ic_share</item>
</style>
```

I downloaded Material Vector assets, added shadow in Adobe Illustrator, imported it to PNG. But the Android Studio's Image Asset/Action Bar and Tab Icons mess up with it I didn't get why - it removed the shadow and colors went different even with Custom 'Theme' so I did different dpi image sizes by myself and that's what I got. That's quite what I wanted

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFhQP.jpg

Comment: I ended up using the same trick as you. I downloaded my icons there https://material.io/icons/ and I used the drop shadow feature in gimp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,  I don't know how to do it with simple button, if you could change `Button` with `FloatingActionButton` you may use `elevation` for making a shadow.

> **`Floating Action Button` (`FAB`)** is simply a circle button with some drop shadow that unbelieveably could change the world of design. No
>    surprise why it becomes a signature of `Material Design`. So let's start
>    with this thing. Add `FAB` in layout file with `FloatingActionButton` and wrap it with `FrameLayout` since it needs some parent to make it aligned at bottom right position of the screen.

and

> The shadow depth is automatically set to the best practices one, `6dp`
>   at idle state and `12dp` at pressed state. Anyway you are allowed to
>   override these values by defining `app:elevation` for idle state's
>   shadow depth and `app:pressedTranslationZ` for press state's.
>
> From: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en

Of course, you can customize by adding your icon. I'm pretty sure, that `play` icon as you have on button is in `Material Design` library.

You can also grab it here: https://design.google.com/icons/

To resume, I advice you learn something more about `FloatingActionButton`, which alows you to add some nice effect like elevation/shadow and others good things from Material library.

Hope it make your development easier and your app more beautiful.

Comment: check out the idea I came up, if you want

Comment: really like your idea +1